# Slice border of 2D NumPy array by integer value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I would like to slice a 2D NumPy array by an integer value, but I cannot find a way to do this properly. I need to slice the "border" of the matrix by a certain number of rows/columns.

Say the array is:

```
a = np.reshape(np.arange(25),(5,5))
print a

[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]

slice_val = 1

b = a[:-slice_val,:-slice_val]
print "\n", b
```

What I get is:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [10 11 12 13]
 [15 16 17 18]]
```

, but I want something like this:

```
[[6  7  8 ]
 [11 12 13]
 [16 17 18]]
```

Comment: `[slice_val:-slice_val,slice_val:-slice_val]`. I think this does it

Comment: In that case all you need is `b = a[slice_val:-slice_val,slice_val:-slice_val]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`b = a[slice_val:-slice_val, slice_val:-slice_val]`

to slice the borders by slice_val.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=np.ones(25).reshape(5,5)
arr
slice_of_array=arr[1:4,1:4]
slice_of_array
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it