# How to cut 25% of image from each side

Tags: python, matplotlib, crop

I'm trying to find a way to cut 25% from each side of the image. 
I was trying with this `cutted_data = data[1:645,1:645]` but it's not what I'm looking for.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img

image_name = 'image.jpg'

data = plt.imread('image.jpg')
cutted_data = data[...?]

print(data)
print(np.shape(data))

plt.subplot(231)
plt.imshow(data)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Obraz w naturalnych kolorach')

plt.subplot(234)
plt.imshow(cutted_data)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Przycięty obraz')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you mean 25 % in both x and y dimensions? do you want 12.5 % from each side, or 25 % from one side?

Comment: 25% from top, 25% from bottom, 25% from  left and  25 % from right

Comment: Related: [Slice border of 2D NumPy array by integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36411483/7851470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
data = plt.imread('image.jpg')
rows, cols = data.shape[:2]
cut_data = data[rows//4:-rows//4, cols//4:-cols//4]
```